# How to copy "just files" recursively

Tags: cp, recursive

Suppose I have this structure for folder0 and subfolders and files in it.

```
   folder0
      subfolder01
        file011
        file012
      subfolder02
        file021
      file01
      file02
```

I want to copy all files in main folder `folder0` to somewhere else, such that all file be in one directory? How Can I do that? I used

```
cp --recursive folder0address targetfolderaddress
```

But subfolders copied to target folder. I just want all files in directory and sub directories not folders.
I mean something like the below in target folder:

```
targetfolder
  file011
  file012
  file021
  file01
  file02
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find folder0 -type f -exec cp {} targetfolder \;
```

With GNU `coreutils` you can do it more efficiently:

```
find folder0 -type f -exec cp -t targetfolder {} +
```

The former version runs `cp` for each file copied, while the latter runs `cp` only once.

Comment: Can you please add explanation of why the GNU variant is more efficient?

Comment: @codeforester Running `cp` once vs. running it for each file.  `-t` is needed because `find ... -exec cp {} targetfolder +` is invalid syntax (`{}` must come at the end).

Comment: Haha! Thanks. You saved me. It works :) ... but what  `\;` do at end of first?

Comment: @SirSaleh It marks the end of the `-exec`ed command.

Answer (score 4):

With zsh, thanks to [`**` for recursive globbing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing) and the [glob qualifier `.`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to match only regular files:

```
cp -p folder0/**/*(.) targetfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using xargs

```
 find folder0 -type f | xargs -I {} cp -v {} targetfolder;
```

Use -v to show what is hapenning.